The trend in pronouncing terminal /z/ as /s/, for example /s/ “noose” instead of /z/ “news”
Addendum added below.
Searching for answers on this is frustrating, though I did look first.
I jokingly keep asking myself, “Am I the only one hearing this /z/ → /s/ trend?” A regular, daily example can be heard on NPR radio. The majority of their radio reporters end their report with the sign-off, “This is Alan Brown, NPR Noose.”
So, my questions are more of a polling of the readers who choose to engage: who else has noticed this themselves, and how or where are trends like these identified and discussed in the greater community?
Addendum 10/14
In the paragraph above it stated the /z/ to /s/ change, and my mention of NPR Noose was its example. I could have written “‘NPR Noose’ instead of ‘NPR News’” to be more clear.
Arguably, it’s lazy. It’s the same configuration but without the effort to vibrate the vocal folds, thus the ’lazy’ moniker. It’s a onion skin thin change, but still arguably a lazy change of direction in the production of language.
The Question
I still hear it happening. I’m wondering if there is a clearinghouse somewhere where it’s tracked. Probably not. I suspect it’ll get tracked through three or four grad school student’s research projects somewhere in Washington state, or Belgium or such.
Linguistics fascinates me. Please understand that to me it’s a well. Its round brick wall mark its location.
Peeking over the wall and into its dark depths, its contents become n-dimensionally huge. I read through some of the “pre-fortis clipping” content referred to by
Janus Bahs Jacquet (I can’t get the @ reference to work…) and think, “Does this ever end!”
Part of the value to me in the interaction between us is the never ending depth of learning offered. I never would have imagined the breadth of continued areas of understanding that are possible. I doubt I’d have made a connection to Yiddish, Y-cluster reductions, elisions, or Yod-droppings, and so on.
Though this sentence may sound like babbling, “learning linguistics helps me formalize, externally, the intangible, internal processes that happen in-the-moment when communicating.” Yiddish has a term describing how, to the uninitiated, text can look worthless or gibberish to the uninitiated. It’s a paradoxical question of awareness and consciousness.

The question will probably be closed, as it's not really in this site's scope to make a poll. When I clicked on this question, I sort of expected it to be about the name for this phenomenon (final devoicing?).

What is “NPR Noose”? Google gives only four hits apart from this question. The normal English word noose (‘loop with running knot’) is pronounced /nuːs/ in Modern English, not /nuːz/; i.e., it rhymes with loose, not lose. But final devoicing in fricatives is quite normal in English, so (partially or fully) devoicing final /z/ to [s] before pausa is common enough.

@JanusBahsJacquet Author of this question probably meant that he heard "NPR News" (which ends with /z/) as "NPR Noose" (which ends with /s/).

@Arfrever Oh, that would make sense! The two aren’t a minimal pair to me (/nuːs/ vs /njuːz/), so I didn’t make the connection. Of course, even if people do devoice the final sibilant phonetically, it’s still voiced phonemically, and pre-fortis clipping does not apply: the vowel in news is still longer than the one in noose.

@JanusBahsJacquet Most American dialects supposedly have /nj/ → /n/ change (instance of yod-dropping).

I listen to NPR every day and I do not hear noose.

@Arfrever Yes, that’s why I specified that I don’t, which is why I didn’t make the connection at first.

@Lambie that may be a regional phenomenon. It could also be a bias in hearing what’s not there because it’s what you’re expecting to hear. It presents more fodder for even more friendly arguments.

noose and news (AmE) are not the same. noose has a longer vowel sound than news, to begin with.

@Arfrever Once one starts listening for it, one hears news /njuz/ quite commonly in American English, but this may be a matter of region, register, or even socio-economic/educational status. Perhaps. I don't know what to attribute this to, but saying  /njuz/ is hardly uncommon in some segments of the American population. Probably there is no single reason for it, but several.

@Lambie I rather wonder why you might think that noose has a "longer" vowel than does news, as it all seems exactly opposite that to me! This is just like bead having a longer vowel than both beat or Pete, or both tied and dyed having a longer vowel than tight, or league having a longer vowel than leak — and all for the selfsame reason that noöne I know of ever disputes.

It’s been migrated to English Language & Usage Experts Exchange, but I’m stumped on how to reopen it there to restart its life. I’m lost on what to do and how to do it. Any suggestions? Thanks for all your input so far, it’s been valuable!
